# Google Crawl Errors - Unreachable error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jrubyonrails

My site has been successfully verified against Google Webmaster. My crawler access with the robot.txt is also 200 (Success). However, when I check "Crawl errors", nearly every page is "unreachable", including the domain main page itself. The only page that gets crawled with no error are the attachment/file page (e.g. pdf, xls, jpg etc.).  This is really strange.

My web is created by Ruby on Rails and using MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the pages take a long time to render? I suspect Google's crawler gives up if the page takes too long to respond. Consider putting Varnish in front of public pages that are expensive and don't contain any user-related or dynamic content?

Comment: the url is www.supertooling.com

Comment: Also one more thing is if I do a search on google with "site:supertooling.com" the only result shown are PDF's .. none of the page are getting indexed.

Comment: Looks like DNS. I've tried it with curl and it's unresponsive. I also can't reach it in a browser. curl -v http://www.supertooling.com
* About to connect() to www.supertooling.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 219.148.38.162...  (nothing further)

Comment: what would cause such a DNS blockage and is there anyway I could resolve that?

Comment: It could be anything, sorry! If I were you I'd move host or nameservers. http://dnstools.com/?count=1&lookup=on&wwwhois=on&arin=on&checkp=on&portNum=80&ping=on&all=on&target=www.supertooling.com&submit=Go! reports DOWN. http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/supertooling.com reports UP.